# Refresh MVC View on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a MVC view which contains a year dropdown and a submit button. By default the current year (i.e. 2017 year) data is loaded on page load and it works fine but when I select some other year from the dropdown its not refreshing the view. Please see the code below:

**HistoricData.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label for="year">Year</label>
            <select id="year" name="year" class="form-control">
                <option>2017</option>                    
                <option>2016</option>
                <option>2015</option>
                <option>2014</option>
                <option>2013</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <button id="btnData" class="btn btn-default" onclick="GetData()">Get Data</button>

        <table id="tblData" class="table table-condensed table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>ID</th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Date/Time</th>  
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>    
            @foreach (var d in Model.AllData)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@d.ID</td>
                    <td>@d.Name</td>
                    <td>@d.DateTime</td>                   
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

**Script:**

```
function GetData() {   
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    year: $("#year option:selected").text()
                }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"                
            });
        }
```

**Controller: HistoricDataController.cs**

```
//this gets called on page load
public ActionResult HistoricData()
{
    var year = 2017;
    return View(GetHistoricData(year));            
}

//trying to call this method to refresh the data with the year selected
public ActionResult GetData(int year)
{
    var model = GetHistoricData(year);
    return View("HistoricData", model);
}

private SomeData GetHistoricData(int year)
{
    return SomeData;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You missed a part when you have to handle response, for that you can add callback on `success` and insert response (`HistoricData` view) to relevant place. Also in your case better to use `GET` rather than `POST`

```
       $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetData")',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                year: $("#year option:selected").text()
            }),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) { $("#somePlace").html(data); },                
        });
```

Comment: And add [httppost] tag in your controller method

Comment: And remember to return `PartialView` rather than `View` from this action. Otherwise, you'll get your whole layout rendered in the AJAX response.

Comment: @IIya.Sulimanov - Sorry I forgot to add the model related details and just added the code.

Comment: When I click the button first the HistoricData() method is getting called and then the GetData(int year) is getting called but the data is not refreshed at all.